# Creating SO return via screen based webservices throwing error [PXRowPersistingException: Error #4: 'RevisionID' cannot be empty]

Tags: acumatica

We had webservice integration and it was working all the way, but suddenly it started to throw the below error when creating a RC type order. Dont understand what exactly is going wrong. We didnt update anything so i believe this is some data related issue.

I tried the same process via UI and it is not giving this error. Please assist. Your help is deeply appreciated.

> PX.Data.PXRowPersistingException: Error #4: 'RevisionID' cannot be
>   empty.
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> PX.Data.PXRowPersistingException: Error #4:
>   'RevisionID' cannot be empty.    at
>   PX.Data.PXDefaultAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender,
>   PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)    at
>   PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation) 
>   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row)    at
>   PX.Objects.CS.SharedRecordAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender,
>   PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)    at
>   PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation) 
>   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row)    at
>   PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)    at
>   PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)    at
>   PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()    at
>   PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.Persist()    at
>   PX.Data.PXSave`1.d__2.MoveNext()    at
>   PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()    at
>   PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext()    at
>   PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1,
>   PXFilterRow[] A_2)    at
>   PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()    at
>   PX.Api.ScreenUtils.Submit(String screenId, Command[] commands,
>   SchemaMode schemaMode, PXGraph& graph, String& redirectContainerView,
>   String& redirectScreen, Boolean mobile, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
>
>   at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1
>   commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, Boolean mobile, PXGraph& forceGraph,
>   String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Dictionary`2
>   viewFilters)    at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id,
>   IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode)    at
>   PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

**EDIT**

The autonumbering is enabled for this order type and the code is as below. Acumatica version 6.00.1384

As mentioned before, this code was working correctly. suddenly the behavior changed and i dont know what is the reason.

```
    apitest.Screen context = BuisnessLogicACU.context;
                        SO301000Content SOSchema;

                        try
                        {
                            SOSchema = context.SO301000GetSchema();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            BuisnessLogicACU.contextLogin();
                            SOSchema = context.SO301000GetSchema();
                        }              
                        SOSchema.Actions.LSSOLineBinLotSerial.Commit = true;
                        SOSchema.Actions.CreateReceiptAction.Commit = true;

                        //HEADER INFO
                        AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] commands = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[]
                    {
                        new Value
                        {
                            Value = returnInterfaceStatus.SalesOrderType,
                            LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.OrderType
                        },
                        SOSchema.Actions.Insert,

                        new Value 
                        {
                            Value = "false", 
                            LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.Hold
                        },
                        new Value 
                        {
                            Value = OrderStatus == POSOrderstatus.Normal ? (ConfigValues.POSNormalCustomerID ?? CustomerID) : CustomerID,  
                            LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.Customer
                        },
                        new Value 
                        {
                            Value = BizDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)BizDate).ToLongDateString() : "", 
                            LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.Date
                        },
                        new Value 
                        {
                            Value = BizDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)BizDate.Value).ToLongDateString() : "", 
                            LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.RequestedOn
                        },                   
                        new Value 
                        {
                            Value = POSID, 
                            LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.ExternalReference
                        },                
                        new Value 
                        {
                            Value = SIPosOrdrCreatedBy, 
                            LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.POSOrdrBy
                        },                
                        new Value 
                        {
                            Value = CustomerTaxZone, 
                            LinkedCommand = SOSchema.FinancialSettingsFinancialInformation.CustomerTaxZone
                        }
                    };

     AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] commandline = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[]
                                {
                                 SOSchema.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.InventoryID, 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.InventoryID 
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = SIOutletCode, 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.Warehouse
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.Quantity.ToString(), 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.Quantity,
                                    Commit = true
                                },                         
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.UnitPrice.ToString(), 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.UnitPrice
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.Uom, 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.UOM
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = (line.DiscTotal ?? 0).ToString(), 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.DiscountAmount
                                },
                                  new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = (line.LineTotal ?? 0).ToString(), 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.ExtPrice
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.DiscType ?? "", 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSDiscType
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.LineType ?? "", 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSLineType
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.VoucherSerial ?? "", 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSVoucherSerial
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.PromoID ?? "", 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSPromoID
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.PromoType ?? "", 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSPromoType
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = (line.PromoPct ?? 0).ToString(), 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSPromoPct
                                },
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.PromoBaseItem ?? "", 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSPromoBaseItem
                                },
                                //new Value 
                                //{
                                //    Value = SalesPerson, 
                                //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.SalespersonID
                                //},
                                new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = line.Remarks ?? "", 
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.NoteText,
                                    Commit = true 
                                },
                                 new Value 
                                {
                                    Value = POSID,
                                    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.PackUoM,
                                    Commit = true 
                                }
                            };
                            commands = commands.Concat(commandline).ToArray();

  AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] save = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] {
                        SOSchema.Actions.Save                       
                    };
                    commands = commands.Concat(save).ToArray();
  AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] returnResult= new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] {                 
                SOSchema.OrderSummary.OrderType,
                SOSchema.OrderSummary.OrderNbr,
                SOSchema.OrderSummary.Status
            };
                commands = commands.Concat(returnResult).ToArray();

                var SOrder = context.SO301000Submit(commands)[0];
```

Comment: Can you please provide with Acumatica version and the commands that you are using in the Screen API call?

Comment: Can you please provide your code as well? It can be good if you can create minimal code that can reproduce your issue

Comment: please see the updated question.

Comment: any assistance?

Comment: In my updated answer below is the closest set of SOAP commands that can be run on brand new 6.00.1384 website with only Sales Demo deployed. **And it runs without any issues.** Not sure how to reproduce reported issue on local machine without exact steps from you.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error message several times so far and usually it was caused by incorrect set of API commands resulting in update of existing Transfer order instead of creating of a new one.

Make sure you pass `Insert` action after you set **OrderType** to ***TR***, if autonumbering is enabled for Numbering Sequence of the **TR** order type:

```
Screen context = new Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.Url = "http://localhost/StackOverflow/Soap/SO301000.asmx";
context.Login(username, password);
try
{
    Content salesOrderSchema = PX.Soap.Helper.GetSchema<Content>(context);
    var commands = new Command[]
    {
        new Value
        {
            LinkedCommand = salesOrderSchema.OrderSummary.OrderType,
            Value = "TR"
        },
        salesOrderSchema.Actions.Insert,
        new Value
        {
            LinkedCommand = salesOrderSchema.OrderSummary.DestinationWarehouse,
            Value = "RETAIL"
        },
        salesOrderSchema.Actions.Save,
        salesOrderSchema.OrderSummary.OrderNbr
    };
    var transferOrder = context.Submit(commands);
}
finally
{
    context.Logout();
}
```

Or, if autonumbering is disabled for Numbering Sequence of the **TR** order type, you should set `OrderNumber` instead of the `Insert` action:

```
Screen context = new Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.Url = "http://localhost/StackOverflow/Soap/SO301000.asmx";
context.Login(username, password);
try
{
    Content salesOrderSchema = PX.Soap.Helper.GetSchema<Content>(context);
    var commands = new Command[]
    {
        new Value
        {
            LinkedCommand = salesOrderSchema.OrderSummary.OrderType,
            Value = "TR"
        },
        new Value
        {
            LinkedCommand = salesOrderSchema.OrderSummary.OrderNbr,
            Value = "NEWNUMBER"
        },
        new Value
        {
            LinkedCommand = salesOrderSchema.OrderSummary.DestinationWarehouse,
            Value = "RETAIL"
        },
        salesOrderSchema.Actions.Save,
        salesOrderSchema.OrderSummary.OrderNbr
    };
    var transferOrder = context.Submit(commands);
}
finally
{
    context.Logout();
}
```

Below is the closest set of SOAP commands that I was able to run on brand new 6.00.1384 website with only Sales Demo deployed. **And it runs without any issues.** Not sure how to reproduce reported issue on local machine without exact steps from you.

```
Screen context = new Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.Url = "http://localhost/SOReturn/Soap/SO301000.asmx";
context.Login(Login, Password);

var SOSchema = context.GetSchema();

SOSchema.Actions.LSSOLineBinLotSerial.Commit = true;
SOSchema.Actions.CreateReceiptAction.Commit = true;

//HEADER INFO
var headerCommands = new Command[]
{
    new Value
    {
        Value = "RC",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.OrderType
    },
    SOSchema.Actions.Insert,

    new Value
    {
        Value = "false",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.Hold
    },
    new Value
    {
        Value = "ABARTENDE",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.Customer
    },
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = BizDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)BizDate).ToLongDateString() : "",
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.Date
    //},
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = BizDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)BizDate.Value).ToLongDateString() : "",
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.RequestedOn
    //},
    new Value
    {
        Value = "TEST",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.ExternalReference
    },
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = SIPosOrdrCreatedBy,
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.OrderSummary.POSOrdrBy
    //},
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = CustomerTaxZone,
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.FinancialSettingsFinancialInformation.CustomerTaxZone
    //}
};

var commandline = new Command[]
{
    SOSchema.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,

    new Value
    {
        Value = "AACOMPUT01",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.InventoryID
    },
    new Value
    {
        Value = "WHOLESALE",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.Warehouse
    },
    new Value
    {
        Value = "10.0",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.Quantity,
        Commit = true
    },
    new Value
    {
        Value = "234.01",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.UnitPrice
    },
    new Value
    {
        Value = "EA",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.UOM
    },
    new Value
    {
        Value = "50.0",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.DiscountAmount
    },
    new Value
    {
        Value = "4500.00",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.ExtPrice,
        Commit = true
    },
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = line.DiscType ?? "",
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSDiscType
    //},
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = line.LineType ?? "",
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSLineType
    //},
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = line.VoucherSerial ?? "",
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSVoucherSerial
    //},
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = line.PromoID ?? "",
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSPromoID
    //},
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = line.PromoType ?? "",
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSPromoType
    //},
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = (line.PromoPct ?? 0).ToString(),
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSPromoPct
    //},
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = line.PromoBaseItem ?? "",
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.POSPromoBaseItem
    //},
    new Value
    {
        Value = "Remarks",
        LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.NoteText,
        Commit = true
    },
    //new Value
    //{
    //    Value = POSID,
    //    LinkedCommand = SOSchema.DocumentDetails.PackUoM,
    //    Commit = true
    //}
};

var commands = headerCommands.Concat(commandline).ToArray();

Command[] save = new Command[] 
{
    SOSchema.Actions.Save
};
commands = commands.Concat(save).ToArray();
Command[] returnResult = new Command[] 
{
    SOSchema.OrderSummary.OrderType,
    SOSchema.OrderSummary.OrderNbr,
    SOSchema.OrderSummary.Status
};
commands = commands.Concat(returnResult).ToArray();

var SOrder = context.Submit(commands)[0];
```

Comment: Hi, I have checked and the autonumbering is enabled, i have the insert command too. Please check the updated question. thanks for your reply.